# Docker Swarm initialization in AWS :Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: error installing docker:

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, devops, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I am trying to build docker swarm cluster in AWS using the below git:
https://github.com/singh-ashok25/aws-swarm-docker/
Here when the host machine tries to create manager nodes and worker nodes using docker machine command:
docker-machine create 
--driver amazonec2 
--amazonec2-region ap-south-1 
--amazonec2-security-group swarm 
worker1 &
I am getting the error:
Error creating machine: Error running provisioning: error installing docker:
Let me know if there is any problem in this command.

I am expecting the solution to be that:
Node creation should be successful and docker should be installed in the cluster nodes without any error.